# Does there exist any positive integer $n$ such that $e^n$ is an integer (to show $\log 2$ is irrational)?

Tags: number-theory, logarithms, exponential-function, transcendental-numbers, rationality-testing

> Does there exist any positive integer $n$ such that $e^n$ is an integer ?

I was in particular trying to prove $\log 2$ is  irrational; now if it is rational, then there are relatively prime integers $p,q$ both positive  such that $\log2 =p/q$ that is $e^p=2^q$ is an integer. I wanted to reach a contradiction.

Comment: No since the number $e$ is transcendental.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: I don't know about transcendental ; can you please give a proof ?

Comment: The proof $e$ is transcendental is probably too long to put in an answer here.  "Transcendental" means it is not a solution of a polynomial equation with integer coefficients.  In particular, $e$ is not a root of an equation of the form $X^n-m$ as marwalix says.

Comment: It's easy to prove that $\log_{10} 2$ is irrational.

Comment: @GEdgar : Is there any other way out to prove $\log 2$ is irrational ?

Comment: @GEdgar : Well I know how to prove $\log 2$ is irrational base $10$ but I am trying to prove here for base $e$ ...

Comment: Probably.  Take the proof that $e$ is irrational, adapt it so show $e^m$ is irrational for integer $m$.

Comment: See http://people.math.sc.edu/filaseta/gradcourses/Math785/Math785Notes3.pdf and http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Miscellaneous/irrationality.html.

Comment: @GEdgar : Well I know the irrationality prove of $e^m$ but here I only need $e^m$ is not an integer , isn't  there any easier proof?

Answer (score 2):

No $e$ is transcendantal and if there were integers $n$ and $m$ such that $e^n=m$ and therefore would be algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ as a root of the polynomial $X^n-m$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that for some couple $(n,m)$ of natural numbers we have $e^n=m$, then $\tanh(n)\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Since $\tanh z=\frac{d}{dz}\log\cosh z$, a [continued fraction representation for $\tanh n$](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Tanh/10/) is given by:

$$ \tanh n = \cfrac{1}{\frac{1}{n}+\cfrac{1}{\frac{3}{n}+\cfrac{1}{\frac{5}{n}+\cfrac{1}{\frac{7}{n}+\cfrac{1}{\frac{9}{n}+\ldots}}}}} \tag{1} $$
and it is not difficult to prove that such expression cannot be equal to some finite standard continued fraction. This leads to $\tanh n\not\in\mathbb{Q}$, hence to $e^n\not\in\mathbb{N}$ as wanted.